# Strange link behavior in codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, hyperlink

This is one of those problems that make me question my sanity. I'm using php, codeigniter framework, removing index.php from URL with mod rewrite in htaccess.

I'm at this address

```
http://localhost/health/users/bob/progress/
```

I click a link that takes me to

```
http://localhost/health/users/bob/progress/01-04-15
```

Then I click on a link that takes me back to

```
http://localhost/health/users/bob/progress/
```

Now here's the strange thing. I click on the same link that earlier took me to

```
http://localhost/health/users/bob/progress/01-04-15
```

But instead, now it's taking me to

```
http://localhost/health/users/bob/progress/progress/01-04-15
```

I've gone through the steps a dozen times now. This is definitely the behavior it's giving me. It even happens when I do a full refresh. I actually have to visit a different address, then return to get the link at

```
http://localhost/health/users/bob/progress/
```

to work properly again. I'm guessing it's either related to the mod rewrite, or some other rewrite behavior in the codeigniter framework.

Comment: Strange behavior does not occur at programing unless you did something that you cannot figure out.Did you wrote the code?what is your user function under health controller (or bob function under users controller) look likes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you are using a relative path for the link that goes something like:

```
<a href="/somerelativepath">link here</a>
```

I would suggest that you use CI's base_url instead so that the link becomes absolute:

```
<a href="<?=base_url()?>/nowabsolutepath">link here</a>
```

the base_url is set on your configuration file. Please let us know how it goes!

Comment: That definitely works and base_url keeps me from having to change code when moving to a different directory structure, so definitely a check mark, but I definitely don't understand what was causing the issue in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your link looks something like the following, and because of that it get's appended to the current url

```
href="progress/01-04-15"
```

Try making your link using absolute path, preferably appending it with base_url or current_url from codeigniter + progress/date.

```
href="http://localhost/health/users/bob/progress/01-04-15"
```

That way you will get to the correct link every time, instead of appending it to current url.